# How to schedule a google-bigQuery so its results would import to spreadsheet on a daily basis?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I wrote a bigQuery query that returns the number of customers in the system, updated to the time I run the query.
I want to schedule the query so everyday I'll get the number of customers in the current day. I want to import the data automatically to a spreadsheet, so eventually I'll have a summary table, broke down by days, as following:

```
Date    Number of Customers
7/5/2019    1000
7/6/2019    993
7/7/2019    1008
7/8/2019    1020
```

How can I import the data automatically everyday to the next cell so it won't overwrite the previous day?

Thanks!

The bigQuery query is simple:

```
select
count(distinct s.customer) as numberOfCustomers,
current_timestamp() as loadingDate
from `dbo.customers` as s
where s.status = 'active'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write an HTTP enabled [GCF](https://cloud.google.com/functions/)(Google Cloud Functions) which will run the query and save the result to the spreadsheet. Then use [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) to invoke the GCF endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use BigQuery schedule to run your query on a daily basis and save the result to a destination table.

**Step 1 - Write your query in the editor**
[image]

**Step 2 - Define your scheduler**

[image]

**Step 3 - access your data from spreadsheet**

Now you can access this data from your spreadsheet like you access any other BigQuery table

Answer (score 1):

You can also write an [AppsScript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery) in your spreadsheet and use [time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to run it.